# What version of spring security works with java 1.4?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a project that uses java 1.4, Struts 1, running on WAS 6 and I need to implements Spring Security, for show some components by a ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER, what version of spring security it´s compatible with my project and i neeed to know if the configuration is like the tutorials for spring security 3.0.x that uses the web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html):

> Spring Security 2.0.x requires a minimum JDK version of 1.4 and is
>   built against Spring 2.0.x. It should also be compatible with
>   applications using Spring 2.5.x.

But when it comes to security, I would not use end-of-life products.